# Create a Windows application without .net framework or Visual C++?

Tags: windows

I want to create a Windows application which does not require any framework such as Visual C++ or .NET Framework.

Kind of like CCleaner, or all the browsers or TeamViewer etc....

What programming language and compiler is used to achieve this?

Comment: c++ and cl.exe and link.exe for example

Comment: @RbMm, I did not understand what you mean by that, please elaborate, I am kind of a newbie and have always used .NET for my needs.

Comment: the question is too broad. so and answer equal to question. possible use c++ for example without .net and crt. are this you ask ?

Comment: I want to learn more about "c++ and cl.exe and link.exe". Can you suggest me a place where I can get started on it?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, frameworks reduce the effort needed to build an app.

There are also other frameworks that are cross-platform, unlike Visual C++ and .NET Framework.

If what you want is a cross-platform solution that requires no installation of dependencies, you could try someting like:

- [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)
- [Qt](https://www.qt.io/)
- [GTK+](https://www.gtk.org/)
- [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)
- [Intel C++ Compilers](https://software.intel.com/en-us/c-compilers)

Or for a completely framework-less solutions, you can try something like what [RbMm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6401656) suggested in the comments of the question (c++ and cl.exe and link.exe).

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the answer I was looking for!

Comment: @user5793353 Glad it helped! Feel free to ask antything that would help you to clear your path trough this. I've made some dependency-free apps and I know how hard it can be for an .NET developer. As I appreciate you want to build a GUI solution, is this correct?

Comment: No actually, it's not a GUI application. It's simply an application that does it's task in the background. I am having a hard time deciding between the three. Which one do you recommend?

Comment: I am also interested in RbMm's suggestion. Where can I get started on that?

Comment: @user5793353 `cl.exe` is the Visual C++ compiler (command line version), and `linker.exe` is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-options). Source code should be on C++. The idea is to write a sandard Visual C++ app and statically link it (as described on [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ab187afb-3af0-44ba-a03c-dde9e5208a1a/static-link-to-vc-runtime?forum=vclanguage)) so the app doesn't require any Visual C++ runtime installation to run. This solution only works on Windows.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I cannot thank you enough mishamosher!

Comment: @user5793353 You could upvote/accept the answer if it really helped, so other users can benefit from this information (and know beforehand that it worked). You can find a lot of information for this specific issue in the internet by searching `static linking [language (c++, c, etc.)]` in your favourite search engine. In fact, the no-runtime install apps are almost always statically linked and written in a languague that doesn't generate intermediate code (like C/C++).

Answer (score 0):

You could use Delphi. I have used it for years to create Windows apps that do not need the .net framework. Delphi is easier to learn than C or C++. Do a google search for "Delphi Community Edition".